# How do I uninstall elegance colors theme from Ubuntu Gnome Shell?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, themes

I updated from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 and I noticed that elegance colors is not working. I tried doing the things it listed from the trouble shoot page on github but no luck.

https://github.com/numixproject/elegance-colors

I've decided to uninstall it and reinstall it again to see if that works. I don't know how to uninstall it though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first remove the PPA and then purge the `gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors` package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:satyajit-happy/themes
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-theme-elegance-colors
```

Also check if there are any folders with the theme name in `~/.local/share/themes` or `~/.themes` folder.

Comment: It still shows up on the tweak tool in the shell extension list.

Comment: @J.R. You might have installed it in `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes` folder. check them and remove the respective theme